# How to prevent #REF errors appearing in formulas when referenced workbook is opened

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In my workbook A, I have formulas that reference my workbook B. Once I open workbook B and enable editing, all of the formulas in workbook A show workbook B's worksheet name as #REF (but the filepath and cell references remain). This is incredibly frustrating since I must manually change all of these #REF's back to the worksheet names every single time I want to update workbook B.

This isn't the case for some other workbooks that I have that reference external workbooks. In those cases, when I open the referenced workbook, I will still get errors, but it won't physically change the formulas. Then, once I am done editing the referenced workbook, I can just go and click "Update Values" in the "Edit Links" dialog box.

What is different between these two situations? How can I change the first situation I described into the second situation? Why does Excel physically change the formulas if the structure of the referenced workbook doesn't change?

I do not want to use INDIRECT() formulas as the ranges that I am referencing in the external workbook may change.

Comment: Has the worksheet name changed? Some formulas like vlookup are tolerant of changes, some like countif are not.

Comment: To avoid the problem Use INDIRECT() function on textually referenced File and Sheet names. For example you are using,,`C:\Folder\[A.xls]!Sheet1'!A1` and you are getting `C:\Folder\[A.xls]!#REF'!A1`. Now store File Path, WB & Sheet  name in a cell and rewrite the formula,, `=INDIRECT(D1&"!A1")` will help you.

Comment: ,,cont.,, Or better share sample data & the Formula with us !!

Answer (score 0):

*Once I've solved the same issue by use of the following method:*

- From the **File** Menu click **Option**.
- From **Option list** Click **Trust Center**.
- Click **Trust Center Settings.**
- In Trust Center window click **Protected 
  View.**
- Then Un-tick **Enable Protected View for 
  files located in unsafe locations.**

*This setting change will solve #REF! error problem.*